build_runner fails because of non-existing errors in code
After runnning build_runner build the build fails due to several messages like this from more than one builder (auto_route_generator chosen here):

[SEVERE] auto_route_generator:auto_route_generator on lib/file.dart: This builder requires
Dart inputs without syntax errors. However, package:file.dart (or an
existing part) contains the following errors.
Try fixing the errors and re-running the build.

There are no errors in the code. What's happening and how should we fix this?

There were warnings and info's lints that in the new version of Flutter (3.22.3) triggers the errors and not on previous ones. The analyzer became stricter I think.
